# How to install sssd in Alpine?

Tags: sssd, alpine

I want to install `sssd` in an `Alpine-Linux` container.

I know that Alpine uses `apk add` to install packages but

`apk add sssd` yields no results. Yet the package seems to exist:

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86_64/sssd

Comment: It's useful to note that the link structure indicates the package details: `edge` is the version, `testing` is the repository, `x86_64` is the arch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sssd was only just added to [Alpine edge](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Edge), the development "version", but you are not running this. You will either need to wait until the next stable Alpine release, or run Alpine edge. Remember that edge is not suitable for production usage.